# Create one page on SE to show my notifications for all SE, etc sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, notifications

Rather than visit every SOFU, SE, and meta site every day to see if anyone has answered/replied/voted on my posts, I would like to have one page that consolidates all of these notifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now complete.

1. look for the small indicator on the Stack Exchange logo in the upper right
2. click it to expand a list of network-wide replies to you.

[image: global inbox]

Comment: Does it only list comments and answers, or also revisions, new badges, activity on favorites, etc.?

Comment: @gnome as I said above: "network-wide replies to you."

Comment: Up! Up! Long live the King!!!

Comment: FWIW, the envelope says "replies" on the tooltip but also [covers those](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65599/54262).  I really wasn't sure what you meant when I asked.

Answer (score 5):

This has been asked a few times. Here is something that might be what you're looking for:

http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com

*Disclaimer: I wrote it.*

Comment: That's pretty neat! However, it only appears to show comment responses but not actual answers is that correct?

Comment: @Oliver: Yes. That's correct... though I plan to add more.

Comment: Seems like it's down now.

Comment: It was discontinued, though I forgot to announce it.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the topbar (which replaced the [supercollider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65590/162102)), you can see all your responses (not reputation changes) from your network profile under the inbox tab.  You can get to your network profile from the accounts section of any per-site profile page.