# Aggregate responses from multiple sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create one page on SE to show my notifications for all SE, etc sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/create-one-page-on-se-to-show-my-notifications-for-all-se-etc-sites)

I am slowly getting tired of logging into all the stackexchange sites to see my responses and stats. Is there any way to get that aggregated in one place and eg. see that I got one response on UI and no more today.

Is there an app that helps with this? Or a site?

Comment: For the record, I have created something similar to this. More information here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/