# Could we have a global notifications area for stackexchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create one page on SE to show my notifications for all SE, etc sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/create-one-page-on-se-to-show-my-notifications-for-all-se-etc-sites)

*This might have been discussed elsewhere, but I couldn't think of the most appropriate phrasing when I was looking. Apologies if this is a dupe.*

Would it be possible to have a global notifications area? This way, if I wanted to see if I had any responses to any of my questions across the trilogy sites (and beyond) I'd only have to go to one place. The logical place would appear to be `http://stackexchange.com/`, which already knows that I'm logged in.

How about it guys?

Comment: This has been asked, as [Create one page on SE to show my notifications for all SE, etc sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/) and [Aggregate responses from multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64092/aggregate-responses-from-multiple-sites-closed), but "global notifications" is a good way to phrase it, so this will be a helpful pointer for future searching. Joel says they're ["working on it"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/create-one-page-on-se-to-show-my-notifications-for-all-se-etc-sites/62449#62449)

Comment: ...and you can use my tool in the meantime. See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have designed a tool you can use for this purpose:

[StackCenter](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com)

[image]
<sub>(source: [quickmediasolutions.com](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackcenter.png))</sub>

Comment: Though I noticed it's comments only. I guess there's no point you adding functionality if Joel et al are planning an integrated version. And it's great for the meantime. Thanks again.