# Too many upvotes cause the sidebar vote counter split into two lines

Tags: bug, design

On the sidebar, if there are more than 3 digits in the votes, it starts to split into two lines, and the second line does not carry the background colour of the first line (For instance, green if it has an accepted answer) like so:

[image]

On a website like Meta.SE, such amounts of votes are common, so shouldn't it be necessary to fix this?

Comment: Here is [an example post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/create-one-page-on-se-to-show-my-notifications-for-all-se-etc-sites) - look at the related list.